# Why awk does not work in script file while select somthing between two files

Tags: shell

In my project, I have two files.

The content of file1 is like:

```
bme-zhangyl
chem-abbott
chem-hef
chem-lijun
chem-liuch
chem-lix
chem-nisf
chem-quanm
chem-sunli
chem-taohq
chem-wanggc
chem-wangyg
```

The content of file2 is like:

```
bme-zhangyl bme-zhangmm
phy-dongert phy-zhangwq
chem-lijun phy-zhangwq
ls-liulj bio-chenw
phy-zhangyb phy-zhangwq
mee-xingw mee-rongym
cs-likm cs-hisao
cs-nany cs-hisao
cs-pengym cs-hisao
chem-quanm cs-hisao
cs-likq cs-hisao
cs-wujx cs-liuyp
mse-mar mse-liangyy
ccse-xiezy ccse-xiezy
maad-chensm maad-wanmp
```

Now i have a script file, the content of it is like:

```
 #!/bash/sh
 for i in $(cat file1)
 do
   groupname=`awk '($1=='"$i"'){print $2}' file2`
   echo $groupname
 done
```

But it is unlucky, it displays nothing;
i have tried another way:

```
#!/bash/sh
 for i in $(cat file1)
 do
   groupname=`awk '{if($1=='"$i"')print $2}' file2`
   echo $groupname
 done
```

and

```
 #!/bash/sh
 for i in $(cat file1)
 do
   groupname=`awk '{if($1==$i)print $2}' file2`
   echo $groupname
 done
```

They are all fail. It seems nothing wrong, who can help me?

The correct output should be:

```
bme-zhangmm
phy-zhangwq
cs-hisao
```

Comment: ... and what is the expected output?

Comment: @James Brown see my update

Answer (score 1):

Using bare awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a{print $2}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
bme-zhangmm
phy-zhangwq
cs-hisao
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {        # has file1 strings to a hash
    a[$1]
    next
}
$1 in a {        # if file2 field 1 keyword was hashed from file1
    print $2     # output word from field 2
}' file1 file2
```

**UpdateD**: As a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a{print $2}' file1 file2
```

Comment: i need a script, not a line cmd

Comment: If you add the shebang as `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` you can write the awk code bare as `NR==FNR{ a[$1]; next } $1 in a { print $2 }`. Name the file `foo` and you could run it as `./foo file1 file2`. Makes the args dynamic. Script is still 2 lines (I'd break them out...), but more flexible and maybe more robust.

Answer (score 0):

i have tested:

```
  groupname=`awk '{if($1==" '$i' ") print $2}' UGfrompwdguprst`
```

it works Ok